# Can I plot times when they're given as UNIX timestamps with added milliseconds?

Tags: datetime, gnuplot

*I'm using gnuplot 4.4 on CentOS 6.6.*

I've found many [example](https://newspaint.wordpress.com/2013/09/16/millisecond-time-resolution-scatter-plotting-with-gnuplot/)s online showing that the following (note the use of `%.3S`) will enable timestamps like "`12:42:51.047`" to be parsed and used as X axis values:

```
set xdata time
set format x "%H:%M:%.3S"
set timefmt "%H:%M:%S"
```

However, my input is not like `HH:MM:SS.mmm` but like `SSSSSSSSSS.mmm`, where the integral part is a UNIX timestamp.

I tried the following, but the parsing appeared to have failed since all datapoints rendered at "00:00:00":

```
set xdata time
set format x "%.3s"
set timefmt "%H:%M:%S"
```

[The manual](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.4/gnuplot.pdf) doesn't give any indication that this is possible but, then again, it doesn't say that the `%H:M:%.3S` was going to work, either.
Is it possible to do what I want to do? If so, how?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: The precision must be given only for the output. For parsing, the seconds (or the timestamp) are treated as floating numbers. But reading in a time stamp with milliseconds seems to be supported only since version 4.6.4 (tested here).

Comment: @Christoph: That's frustrating :(

Comment: you can use the unix/linux `date` command to convert from `...SSS.mmm` format to anything that gnuplot can accept. Unfortunately, its a rather expensive process. Hm.. maybe `gawk` time functions would be more efficient. I don't have to use it very much, so indicate if that would work for you and someone else will give you some examples to help. Good luck.

Comment: Why are you doing any of this?  Doesn't it just work, treating the x axis values as floating-point numbers?  Are you trying to control display of axis ticks (which your question says absolutely nothing about)?

Comment: @BenVoigt: The question says absolutely nothing about the axis ticks because it has absolutely nothing to do with them (at least not beyond using them to see whether an attempt at solving the problem has been vaguely successful). :) This is about GNUPlot's _parsing_. I have a file of data, which includes a column of millsecond-res timestamps, and I want GNUPlot to plot this data. It does not correctly parse those timestamps. It's obvious from the way the datapoints end up clumped together in a single vertical line, or otherwise improperly spaced, depending on what silly solution I try.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Moving away from `set xdata time`, which I believe you just suggested, is an interesting idea. If it works it will lead on to my next question, which _will_ be about the X axis tick labels.. ;P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The precision must be given only for the output. For parsing, the seconds (or the timestamp) are treated as floating numbers. But reading in a time stamp with milliseconds seems to be supported only since version 4.6.4 (tested here).

But, there is a workaround: specifying `($1)` instead of `1` in the `using` statement makes gnuplot treat the value as normal floating point number. Note, that I do not set any `timefmt`, since it would be circumvented by this workaround anyway.

Then you must also know, that before version 5, gnuplot's time reference is the 1. Jan. 2000, so you must correct by the respective offset (Unix time stamp of the 1. Jan 2000 is 946684800). So, the following works with gnuplot 4.4:

```
set xdata time
set format x '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S'
plot 'file.dat' using ($1 - 946684800):2
```

Comment: Nice. That's the ticket! :)

Comment: I've only just realised, but the subtraction isn't actually right. Are you sure that 4.4 doesn't also treat the time reference as the UNIX epoch? I make it `using ($1):2` and seem to get the proper times.

Comment: It is correct. I saw your deleted question and I commented it: Add the complete date to the output and you'll see, that it is correct only when you subtract the respective offset.

Comment: False alarm .. and complete co-incidence that using Gnuplot epoch (with `-0`) or UNIX epoch (with `-946684800`) give me the same time-of-day component. Accidentally writing `-94668400` does not :P

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to do anything at all, except stop fighting the default settings.  For this input data:

```
1000000000.001 1
1000000000.002 2
1000000000.003 3
1000000000.004 3
1000000000.005 2
1000000000.006 1
```

The following commands

```
gnuplot> plot "gnuplotdatatest.txt" w l
gnuplot> set yrange [0:4]
gnuplot> replot
```

produce the following output

[image]

Timestamps in SSSSSSSSSS.mmm format are simply (decimal representation of) floating-point numbers, which is how GNUplot treats input columns by default.

Comment: Okay, I guess this is where the whole axis ticks bit _does_ come into it then, so you're right I should have specified that in the question (not realising at the time that it could steer answers). The axis should "look" like a time axis, with "HH:MM:SS" formatting, which this one doesn't. +1 anyway

Answer (score 2):

Newer versions of gnuplot support Unix timestamp format `%s` with fractional parts. You will need to update to 4.6 or 5.x or higher.

Check src/time.c if you're not sure.

Comment: CentOS 6.6 only packages up to 4.4 and since I'm deploying my application as an RPM I don't want to go off the beaten track with dependencies.